# React Native RefreshControl not triggering onRefresh on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, uirefreshcontrol

I've got the following (simplified) setup for my `PersonScreen`, which navigate to `AppointmentScreen`:

```
class PersonScreen {
  state = {
    refreshing: false,
  };

  _onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this._fetchStuff()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ refreshing: false });
      };
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={CONTAINER}>
        <ScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={this._onRefresh} />}
          <ListItem
            key={ITEM.id}
            title={moment(DATETIME).format(FORMAT))}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.navigate('AppointmentScreen', {
                appointment: ITEM,
                refreshParent: this._onRefresh,
              });
            }
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

On the `AppointmentScreen` you make some choices and then to go back the following is performed:

```
const { refreshParent } = navigation.state.params;
refreshParent();
navigation.goBack();
```

The only scenario where this does not work is on iOS. It works as long as I go to `PersonScreen` and refresh. However, if I go from `PersonScreen` to `AppointmentScreen` and back it does trigger the `refreshParent` (which is essentially `_onRefresh`), but then any attempts to pull down to trigger the `RefreshControl`s `onRefresh` function fails. I've also added some `console.log` in the `_onRefresh`, but it doesn't even output anything.

If my `AppointmentScreen` instead looks like this:

```
const { refreshParent } = navigation.state.params;
//refreshParent();
navigation.goBack();
```

Everything works. So I'm experiencing that somehow calling `refreshParent` and then going back makes the following `_onRefresh` from the `RefreshControl` in `PersonScreen` not work.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is the case? As mentioned, I only experience this on iOS, but consistently so on iOS simulator and devices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create an expo version?

also,  your refreshing is `refreshing={refreshing}`  it should be `refreshing={this.state.refreshing}`

Comment: Thanks. I will look into creating an Expo version. it isn't actually built with Expo though.

Comment: Did you try this? Changing refreshing?